# Angularjs How to show hidden data from the selected row in a listBox?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, data-binding, listbox

i got something like this:

A table, with the data of more students...the content is ID, Name, LastName and From.....now i added a new class to the project...its called BankAccount

the students can have 0 or more accounts...

and i added them in a data-binding process to the students...

now i want to select a student, and to show his (if any) accounts in a listBox on the same page...so far i have this code:

the table with the students...

```
    <table border="1" name="tableStud" arrow-selector>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>From</td>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="student in result"
                ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}"
                ng-click="setSelected(student,$index)">
                <td>{{ student.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.mestorodjenja.ime }}</td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


 <select ng-model="student.accounts" multiple="multiple"
                ng-options="account.name for account in student.accounts track by account.id"

        >
        </select>
```

In the controler i got this:

```
$scope.setSelected = function(student, index) {
    $scope.student = student;   
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
};
```

Now the problem is, my list box is showing the accounts for the selected students....but they are all SELECTED and, once i press on one of them, the others disappear, while the pressed one is still selected....

On top of that, once i go on to another student, and come back...all the disappeared accounts from the listBox are still missing....and the old one is also selected...

In the end my question is:

Is it possible to just select the student, and his accounts to be shown on the listBox without being selected....and not disappearing after i press them...?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Seems fine https://jsfiddle.net/twizzlers/pp3b0egh/2/

Comment: no its not the same....my students have more than one acc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your varible for selected student. Like :

```
$scope.setSelected = function(student, index) {
   $scope.selectedstudent = student;   
   $scope.selectedRow = index;
};
```

***HTML*** :

```
 <select ng-model="student.accounts" multiple="multiple"
            ng-options="account.name for account in selectedstudent.accounts track by account.id">
 </select>
```

Comment: sec...i ll try it